# Upload generated csv file to a sftp location in Java

Tags: java, sftp, fileinputstream

I am generating a CSV file using apache commons csv as shown in below code,

```java
Writer writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get("file_name.csv"));
CSVPrinter csvPrinter = new CSVPrinter(writer, CSVFormat.DEFAULT);
csvPrinter.printRecords(headerItems);
```

Now after this I am unable to find out how to send this to a remote sftp location using a username and public key. Should I write the writer object to a file or something else to transfer I am not able to comprehend.

Comment: You appear to be generating a file on the file system, so you should then be able to make an ftp connection to your server, and sen dthe file. There are many libraries to help with this.

Comment: can you please give a small example if possible

Answer (score 0):

you created file_name.csv file on your local computer, now you create InputStream from it

```
InputStream local = new FileInputStream("file_name.csv");
```

then you use that stream to upload the file using some sftp library